# Training loss and accuracy remain the same as well as validation accuracy

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN model with two inputs, but I notice that accuracy for both training and validation remain high and constant. There is probably something wrong with my code. Any help to solve this is welcome.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, Dropout, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional

input_text = Input(shape=(100,), dtype='int32', name='input_text')
meta_input = Input(shape=(2,), name='meta_input')
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1, 
                  output_dim=300, 
                  input_length=100)(input_text)

lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=128, 
                      dropout=0.9, 
                      recurrent_dropout=0.9, 
                      return_sequences=True),
                 merge_mode='concat')(embedding)
pool = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(lstm)
dropout = Dropout(0.5)(pool)
text_output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='aux_output')(dropout)

output = concatenate([text_output, meta_input])

output = Dense(n_codes, activation='relu')(output)


main_output = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='main_output')(output)

model = Model(inputs=[input_text,meta_input], outputs=[output])
optimer = Adam(lr=.001)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='binary_crossentropy', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit([X1, X2], [y],
          validation_data=([X_valid1,X_valid2], [y_valid]),
          batch_size=64, epochs=20, verbose=1)
```

Result:
   training rows: 11416
    validation rows: 2035
    [  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 158]
    Model: "model_6"

---

## Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to

input_text (InputLayer)         [(None, 100)]        0

---

embedding_7 (Embedding)         (None, 100, 300)     889500      input_text[0][0]

---

bidirectional_7 (Bidirectional) (None, 100, 256)     439296      embedding_7[0][0]

---

global_max_pooling1d_7 (GlobalM (None, 256)          0           bidirectional_7[0][0]

---

dropout_7 (Dropout)             (None, 256)          0           global_max_pooling1d_7[0][0]

---

aux_output (Dense)              (None, 1)            257         dropout_7[0][0]

---

meta_input (InputLayer)         [(None, 2)]          0

---

concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 3)            0           aux_output[0][0]
                                                                 meta_input[0][0]

---

## dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 545)          2180        concatenate_7[0][0]

Total params: 1,331,233
Trainable params: 1,331,233
Non-trainable params: 0

---

Train on 11416 samples, validate on 2035 samples
Epoch 1/20
11416/11416 [==============================] - 143s 13ms/sample - loss: 0.0254 - accuracy: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0236 - val_accuracy: 0.9982
Epoch 2/20
11416/11416 [==============================] - 143s 13ms/sample - loss: 0.0233 - accuracy: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0235 - val_accuracy: 0.9982
Epoch 3/20
11416/11416 [==============================] - 150s 13ms/sample - loss: 0.0233 - accuracy: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0233 - val_accuracy: 0.9982
Epoch 4/20
11416/11416 [==============================] - 166s 15ms/sample - loss: 0.0232 - accuracy: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0234 - val_accuracy: 0.9982
Epoch 5/20
11416/11416 [==============================] - 198s 17ms/sample - loss: 0.0232 - accuracy: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0234 - val_accuracy: 0.9982
Epoch 6/20
11416/11416 [==============================] - 236s 21ms/sample - loss: 0.0232 - accuracy: 0.9982 - val_loss: 0.0232 - val_accuracy: 0.9982
Epoch 7/20

Comment: First of all at `main_output` `Dense(1, activation='softmax'` won't work. Change softmax to sigmoid, or change output size to 2 and change the other parameters according to it.

Comment: I changed softmax to sigmoid, but I still the same result.

Comment: Yes this is just one problem. I need some sample data to give you more advice.

Comment: Sorry I was away for a bit.  I have 3 columns: col1 is text, col2 have 6digit numbers and col3 have 9 digit numbers.

Comment: I meant 3 input columns.